# Почему получаю ошибку `copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted`?

Tags: c++

Есть класс в котором есть вот такая переменная

```
PoolWrapper<FrameManager> m_PoolWrapperFrameManager;
```

Вот ее имплементация

```
public:
    PoolWrapper() = default;

    PoolWrapper(TYPE *obj, int index, ObjPool<TYPE> *objPool);

    ~PoolWrapper();

    PoolWrapper(const PoolWrapper &) = delete;

    PoolWrapper(PoolWrapper &&other)
    {
        this->m_index = other.m_index;
        this->m_obj = other.m_obj;
        this->m_objPool = other.m_objPool;

        other.m_index = EMPTY_INDEX;
        other.m_obj = nullptr;
        other.m_objPool = nullptr;
    }
```

Теперь я хочу в эту переменную `m_PoolWrapperFrameManager` мувнуть обьект из очереди.

Делаю это вот так

```
m_PoolWrapperFrameManager = std::move(m_fifo.dequeue());
```

И вот метод `dequeue()`

```
 PoolWrapper<FrameManager> dequeue()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

        while (m_queue.empty())
        {
            // release lock as long as the wait and reaquire it afterwards.
            m_condition.wait(lock);
        }

        PoolWrapper<FrameManager> val = std::move(m_queue.front());
        m_queue.pop();
        return val;
    }
```

В итоге получаю вот такую ошибку

```
error: object of type 'PoolWrapper<FrameManager>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
```

Что делаю не так?

Comment: Для чего добавлена строка `PoolWrapper(const PoolWrapper &) = delete;`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Я хочу явно удалить конструктор копирования, так как в данной имплементации я использую только мув...

Comment: Компилятор не очень умный. Сначала создаётся пустой конструктор, затем оператор присвоения. Проще всего убрать знак присвоения и делать так : `PoolWrapper<FrameManager> val( std::move(m_queue.front()));`

Comment: @AlexGlebe да, оператор присваивания у меня стоит в методе... я не могу внутри метода использовать конструктор как у вас показано

Comment: Скажите компилятор, версию, операционку. Опции компилятора. А так всё гадать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определите оператор присваивания, у вас его а нет.

```
PoolWrapper& operator=(PoolWrapper &&other) {
  this->~PoolWrapper();
  return *new(this) PoolWrapper(std::move(other));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Видимо вы надеетесь на то, что компилятор неявно сгенерирует этот оператор за вас, однако этого не произойдет, так как у вас явно определен конструктор копирования и перемещения. Компилятор никогда не генерирует копирующие / перемещающие конструкторы и операторы присваивания, если явно определен хотя бы один из них. Соответственно в такой ситуации операторы необходимо определять явно.

Кроме того, конструктор перемещения у вас реализован как копирующий: поля класса инициализируются по-умолчанию, а затем им присваиваются новые значения посредством оператора копирования.